# Trying to get message from background script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a problem, when getting message from background script. My mind almost blowed, where is mistake?

**manifest**

```
{
    "name":"Some name",
    "version":"0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description":"extension for Google Chrome",
    "permissions": ["tabs","http://*/*", "https://*/*", "<all_urls>","notifications","contextMenus","alarms","tabs","bookmarks"],
    "content_scripts":[
    {
        "matches":["<all_urls>"],
        "css":["style.css"],
        "js":["content.js","jquery.js"]
    }
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js","jquery.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "icons":{
        "16": "images/icon16.png",
        "48": "images/icon48.png",
        "128": "images/icon128.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "19": "images/icon19.png",           
            "38": "images/icon38.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Order Checker",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    console.log('Loaded!');
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
        greeting: "hello"
    });
    console.log('Sended on '+tab.id+'...');
});
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, _, request) {
    console.log('Getting request...');
    console.log(msg.greeting);
});
```

In background page I'm getting in console 2 messages, as expected. But on content page I don't have any messages, so I think it's problem with code in content.js. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**chrome.tabs.getSelected()** is deprecated from [`Chrome 16`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/whats_new.html#16), use [**chrome.tabs.query()**](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query) instead.

*`Problem in Your Script`*

chrome.tabs.getSelected() returns reference of current selected tab, which  after **load of extension** is  `chrome://chrome/extensions/` so your background page is sending message to extensions page where content scripts `do not execute`

Modify your background script to suit [**chrome.tabs.query()**](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query), you can see messages in console of web pages!

## References

- [tabs.query](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query)